# Loading plain text files in html/Javascript without httpxmlrequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, plaintext

The question is a bit theoretical. 
Suppose I have a local image file that is loaded once in html and could be used in script. For this I write one line:`<img id="myImage" src="myImage.png"/>`

Now suppose I want to do the same but with text. I have a local .txt file. It seems to be an overdo to make an http request for such a simple purpose! 
Using script with `var = "my text here"` seems like a dirty solution, besides the text should be edited in this case.

Is there a way to simplify that? And if not is there an architectural explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `Iframe` :

```
<iframe src="file.txt"></iframe>
```